# Remove grey border around tab button (using FragmentTabHost)

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

I am using FragmentTabHost to get my tabs but a grey border is coming around each tab button. Please guide me to get rid of this grey border. See attachment below :
[image]

I want it to look like :
[image]

My layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tabhost" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Android code is :

```
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);


        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(HOMETAB_TAG).setIndicator("" , getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_selector)), HomeContainerFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(QRTAB_TAG).setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.qr_selector)), QrContainerFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(AROUNDTAB_TAG).setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.around_selector)), AroundContainerFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(SHARETAB_TAG).setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.share_selector)), ShareContainerFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(MORETAB_TAG).setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.more_selector)), MoreContainerFragment.class, null);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

got the work around myself and it worked as required. Thanks.

just used below code :

```
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(HOMETAB_TAG).setIndicator(""), HomeContainerFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(QRTAB_TAG).setIndicator(""), QrContainerFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(AROUNDTAB_TAG).setIndicator(""), AroundContainerFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(SHARETAB_TAG).setIndicator(""), ShareContainerFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(MORETAB_TAG).setIndicator(""), MoreContainerFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_selector);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.qr_selector);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.around_selector);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.share_selector);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.more_selector);

    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
```